# Moving files into another folder but seen as missing

Tags: c#, cefsharp

I seem to be having issues moving some folders and files, i'm using the `cefSharp` library, I initially used the `PrettyBin` from nugent, this did a good job of the other .dll files, I thought i would move the cef files into the `lib` folder too, just to keep everything together.

What i have done:

Program.cs

```
using CefSharp;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace rankjester
{
    internal static class Program
    {
        private static string lib, browser, locales, res;
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        private static void Main()
        {
            lib = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, @"lib\cef\libcef.dll");
            browser = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, @"lib\cef\CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.exe");
            locales = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, @"lib\cef\locales\");
            res = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, @"lib\cef\");
            var libraryLoader = new CefLibraryHandle(lib);
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new FormMain());
        }
    }
}
```

The `lib` paths are all fine and match up, but when i run the software i get:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'CefSharp, Version=86.0.241.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=40c4b6fc221f4138' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'
```

If i comment out those lines things then load as they should, is there anything i have missed?

I also noticed `cefSharp` creates `x86` and `x64` folders each time i run debug, is there a way i can turn this off? any help would be appreciated.

Comment: See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/discussions/3371 for an example.

Comment: Tried all of that to a T, still not working, will keep at it.

Comment: Are you using PrettyBin as well? Just use one.

Comment: Also remove the call to CefLibraryHandle

Comment: Hi, do you mean don't use PrettyBin? i cannot get it working at all, instead of ```lib\cef\``` i just used the ```lib``` folder to store the files (for easiness), i'm getting ```Could not load file or assembly CefSharp.WinForms``` I know it's not seeing the files (hence the error), i have tried: https://pastebin.com/WEAB96CM a lot of different code, is there a way i can check which folder it is looking in so i can start there? thanks for the help.

Comment: Uninstall prettybin. Did you add the entry to your app.config?

Comment: Hi Alex, uninstalled prettybin, i'm getting ```System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'CefSharp.WinForms, Version=87.1.132.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=40c4b6fc221f4138' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'``` even on the minimal test source from ```cefsharp``` installed vc++ 2019, is there any files that need to be in the root of the "Release" folder at all? thanks Alex

Comment: The trouble started when i tried to tidy up the root folder, i tried to put the files in a ```cef``` folder, and the .dll's in a ```lib``` folder, i had to revert back to all files in the root as it was too messy to move it seems.